# how to install firmware for Sharp MX-264N MFP printer

Tags: printer, firmware, multi-function-printer

I have been trying to install a firmware for the Sharp mfp model stated but don't know where to start. Need help from any expert here. The original sd card containing the firmware has failed and I cannot access the original file. I have another sd card that I would like to install the firmware to.

Comment: Have you checked the support section of Sharp's website?

Comment: Have a look at page 219 of thie service manual https://www.manualslib.com/manual/922647/Sharp-Mx-M264u.html?page=219#manual

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The printer is now displaying this message "Err: Failed to expand ARM9 prg". Please confirm that I need a new SD card for this printer. Thanks